# How to find the differences between two objects using IEquatable?

Tags: c#, .net-core, interface, iequatable

I am comparing two same objects by implementing an IEquatable interface on the object. If they are not equal, then update the DB; otherwise, leave it as it is. Here the context is i need to update the table with the data coming from an excel sheet and compare the data and update only when there is a data change.

Below is the code for the same

```
var constructionMaterialTypes = package.GetObjectsFromSheet<ConstructionMaterialTypeExcelDto>(ConstructionDataSheetNames.CONSTRUCTION_MATERIAL_TYPE,
                                                                                              ConstructionDataTableNames.ConstructionMaterialType);
var materialTypes = new List<ConstructionMaterialType>();
foreach (var materialType in constructionMaterialTypes)
{
    var materialTypeId = GetGuidFromMD5Hash(materialType.name);
    List<string> materialTypeNotes = new();

    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(materialType.notes))
    {
        materialTypeNotes.Add(materialType.notes);
    }

    var existingMaterialType = ctx.ConstructionMaterialTypes.SingleOrDefault(cm => cm.Id == materialTypeId);

    var constructionMaterialType = new ConstructionMaterialType
    {
        Id = materialTypeId,
        Name = materialType.name,
        NotesHTML = materialTypeNotes
    };

    if (existingMaterialType != default)
    {
        if (existingMaterialType != constructionMaterialType) // Object comparison happening here 
        {
            existingMaterialType.Name = materialType.name;
            existingMaterialType.NotesHTML = materialTypeNotes;
        }
    }
    else
    {                       
        materialTypes.Add(constructionMaterialType);                       
    }
}
```

and then below is the actual class where I am implementing Iequatable interface

```
public sealed class ConstructionMaterialType : IIdentity<Guid>, IEquatable<ConstructionMaterialType>
{
    [Key]
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public List<string> NotesHTML { get; set; }
    public bool Equals(ConstructionMaterialType other)
    {
        if (other is null)
            return false;

        return this.Id == other.Id
            && this.Name == other.Name
            && this.NotesHTML == other.NotesHTML;
    }
    public override bool Equals(object obj) => Equals(obj as ConstructionMaterialType);
    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        int hash = 19;
        hash = hash * 31 + (Id == default ? 0 : Id.GetHashCode());
        hash = hash * 31 + (Name == null ? 0 : Name.GetHashCode(StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase));
        hash = hash * 31 + (NotesHTML == null ? 0 : NotesHTML.GetHashCode());
        return hash;
    }
}
```

this condition `existingMaterialType != constructionMaterialType` is always true even if both objects are holding the same values, and I have attached the images as well for reference purposes

[image]

[image]

I am not sure where I am doing wrong in the above code. Could anyone please point me in the right direction?
Many thanks in advance

Comment: 1. You did not override the `!=` operator, but you can use `!existingMaterialType.Equals(constructionMaterialType)` instead.
2. Instead of `this.NotesHTML == other.NotesHTML` you might want to use `this.NotesHTML.SequenceEquals(other.NotesHTML) `; in this case, also `GetHashCode()` needs to be adapted

Comment: @KlausGütter. I have used `!existingMaterialType.Equals(constructionMaterialType)` but it is still failing and yeah did not use `!=` operator

Comment: Did you try to debug it? I bet the problem is with `this.NotesHTML == other.NotesHTML`

Comment: The issue does seam to be the `this.NotesHTML == other.NotesHTML`, because when you equate a `List` to another `List` it just checks to see if the references are equal, and not checking if the items inside the lists are the same. You will have to use `(System.Linq) Enumerable.SequenceEqual` or write your own `List` equality method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You did not override the `!=` operator, but you can use `!existingMaterialType.Equals(constructionMaterialType)` instead.
2. `this.NotesHTML == other.NotesHTML` will do a reference comparison of the two list, so even if both contain excactly the same strings, it will return `false` is the two lists are different instances. You might want to use `this.NotesHTML.SequenceEqual(other.NotesHTML)` instead (might need sone adaptation if `NotesHTML` can be `null`).

Note: `GetHashCode` must deliver the same result for all objects that compare equal. So if you change anything in the `Equals` method, you probably also have to change `GetHashCode`. As it is not necessary that objects that compare non-equal have different hash codes, it is an option to just not take into account some properties. Here: just omit the line with `NotesHTML`.

Comment: I did tried `this.NotesHTML.SequenceEqual(other.NotesHTML)`  the same  but it is still failing somewhat and what do you mean by gethashcode needs to be adapted

Comment: Thanks it works well with the first version